# What are the ability modifiers (other than Dex) that can be used when calculating AC?

Tags: dnd-5e, ability-scores, armor-class

As far as my knowledge of D&D goes there are 2 ways to determine AC:

1. **Calculation of AC through Base + Stat modifiers**

   Examples of these AC calculations are:

   - **Unarmored** = 10 + Dex mod
   - **Unarmored defense**, such as Barbarian = 10 + Con mod + Dex mod
   - **Light armors**, such as Leather Armor = 11 + Dex mod
   - **Medium armors**, such as Breastplate = + Dex mod (max 2)
   - **Spells**, such as Mage Armor (AC = 13 + Dex mod)

---

2. **Setting the base AC to a specific value**

   Examples of these AC calculations are:

   - **Heavy Armor**, such as Plate Armor = 18
   - **Racial**, such as Tortle's Natural armor race = 17
   - **Spells** such as Barkskin = 16

---

My interest goes out to the first way of calculating AC.

What are the stat modifiers (**other than Dex**) that can be used when calculating AC?

I already found 2:

- Barbarian's Unarmored Defense = 10 + DEX mod + CON mod
- Monk's Unarmored Defense = 10 + DEX mod + WIS mod

Are there any others that I missed?

Comment: Are you interested in answers that draw on Unearthed Arcana, Planeshift, and other similar information?

Comment: I am interested in answers that draw from official 5e sources and Experimental 5e sources such as Unearthed Arcana. But Planeshift doesn't ring a bell for me. But every 5e source is welcome!

Comment: Does the boost to AC have to be permanent?

Comment: As long as they use Stat modifiers, it is fine for me.

Comment: @InfernoIV: The Plane Shift PDFs are distributed by WotC on their website and on [DMsGuild](https://www.dmsguild.com/browse.php?filters=0_0_0_0_45690_0_0_0), but are not playtested like published content or presented for playtesting; they're essentially James Wyatt's own personal untested "homebrew".

Comment: What's your reasoning for looking for all the different (non-fixed-value) AC calculations? Different AC calculations don't stack anyway; only AC bonuses do. Is it just out of curiosity?

Comment: @V2Blast: I indeed know different AC calculations don't stack. I do know that AC only covers 1 of the 2 sides of D&D: Combat. But I find it annoying and boring that you always have to have either Dex or Str for getting a high AC, the other options that are available are either Class or Race specific. I would like to know what my options are, so: yes it is indeed out of curiosity.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Dexterity, Constitution, and Wisdom can be added permanently to AC. Intelligence can be added for a minute. Charisma can be added through a magic item from *Hoard of the Dragon Queen* or to a single attack. I found no way at all to add Strength to AC.

Below I will provide "the best" methods of adding a given ability modifier to one's Armor Class. By "best" I mean the one that lasts the longest, which, in the case of Charisma, is quite short. This means that features which add Constitution to AC for 1 attack, turn, round, minute, or anything else will not be mentioned/listed:

### [Barbarian's Unarmored Defense feature](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#UnarmoredDefense-52) (Con and Dex):

> While you are not wearing any armor, **your Armor Class equals 10 + your Dexterity modifier + your Constitution modifier.** You can use a shield and still gain this benefit.
>
> - *Player's Handbook* (page 48)

### [Monk's Unarmored Defense feature](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#UnarmoredDefense-226) (Wis and Dex):

> Beginning at 1st level, while you are wearing no armor and not wielding a shield, **your AC equals 10 + your Dexterity modifier + your Wisdom modifier.**
>
> - *Player's Handbook* (page 78)

### Bladesinging Wizard's Bladesong feature (Int):

> [...] You can use a bonus action to start the Bladesong, which **lasts for 1 minute.** It ends early if you are incapacitated, if you don medium or heavy armor or a shield, or if you use two hands to make an attack with a weapon. You can also dismiss Bladesong at any time you choose (no action required).
>
> While your bladesong is active, you gain the following benefits:
>
> - **You gain a bonus to your AC equal to your Intelligence modifier (minimum of +1)** [...]
>
> - *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide* (page 143)

### [Unearthed Arcana's Oath of Heroism Paladin's Glorious Defense feature](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/bard-paladin) (Cha):

> [...] When a creature you can see hits you with an attack roll, you can use your reaction to gain a bonus to AC against that attack, potentially causing it to miss you. **The bonus equals your Charisma modifier (minimum of +1)** [...]
>
> - Bard and Paladin Unearthed Arcana (page 2) [[link to document](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-EloquentHeroics.pdf)]

### An item from *Hoard of the Dragon Queen* (Cha):

> This item is the [Black Dragon Mask](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/black-dragon-mask) which has the following property:
>  **Draconic Mastery.** While you are wearing no armor, you can add your Charisma bonus to your Armor Class.

Thanks to user [David Coffron](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/41726/david-coffron) for pointing out this item!

Comment: You can also add Charisma via [a set of magic items](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/red-dragon-mask) found in *Hoard of the Dragon Queen* and *Rise of Tiamat*

Comment: @davidcoffron Thank you! I'll add that in later today. Unfortunately I haven't found an easy way to sort through magic item descriptions with any sort of ctrl-f function or categorization method that would help with *this* question, so thank you for finding these!