# Is there any way to add your Charisma score to your Armor Class?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, armor-class

Bladesinging wizards add their Intelligence modifier to their AC while singing.

Barbarians get an unarmored AC of 10+Dex+Con

Monks get an unarmored AC of 10+Dex+Wis

What are the ways, if any, in any published material or Unearthed Arcana, to have your Charisma modifier as part of your Armor class calculation?

Comment: Related, possible dupe: [What are the ability modifiers (other than Dex) that can be used when calculating AC?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/160105/52137)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Get a Dragon Mask

Each of the [dragon masks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/hotdq/appendix-c-magic-items#DragonMasks) from *Hoard of the Dragon Queen* lets you add your Charisma modifier to your AC as long as you aren't wearing armor.

> ***Draconic Majesty.*** While you are wearing no armor, you can add your Charisma bonus to your Armor Class.

## Unearth an Oath of Heroism

The Unearthed Arcana paladin [Oath of Heroism](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-EloquentHeroics.pdf) can temporarily add a bonus equal to their Charisma modifier to their AC using *Glorious Defense*:

> When a creature you can see hits you with an attack roll, you can use your reaction to gain a bonus to AC against that attack, potentially causing it to miss you. The bonus equals your Charisma modifier (minimum of +1).

## Become a Swashbuckler (NPC)

But not the normal kind. While the rogue archetype by the same name does not grant such a feature, the [Swashbuckler NPC](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/swashbuckler) has a trait adding it's Charisma modifier to its AC:

> **Suave Defense.** While the swashbuckler is wearing light or no armor and wielding no shield, its AC includes its Charisma modifier.

However as it is a humanoid monster/NPC, the only way to get the trait is through *shapechange* or *true polymorph*, and there are probably better things to do with your 9th-level spells.

Comment: Pedantic note: The swashbuckler is listed as a Nonplayer Character rather than a humanoid monster. Also, the five Dragon Masks are unique artefacts that are extremely hard to get hold of even in the one adventure they appear in.